# How to make a rounded Camera Preview in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

My Goal is to create Circle Shape with the Camera Preview. I tried setting 
a Container with  Boxshape.circle and a Child : The CameraPreview(). But it didn't work. So i tried setting The CameraPreview() in a CircleAvatar(), but it didn't work too. Does anyone have a Solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrap the camera preview with a ClipRRect with its border-radius property defined to determine the curvature of the rounded corners:

```
ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(8.0),
        topRight: Radius.circular(8.0),
        bottomRight: Radius.circular(8.0),
        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(8.0),

      ),
      child: AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: 1,
        child: CameraPreview(controller),

      ),
    )
```

Comment: Rather than doing for every corner, you could achieve the same thing with `borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8))`

Answer (score 2):

> My Goal is to create Circle Shape with the Camera Preview

`CameraPreview` (from the [Flutter Camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) package) provides a series of images (or video). And images can be shaped with clipping (such as `ClipRect`, `ClipRRect`, `ClipOval`, or `ClipPath`).

For a "Circle Shape" you can use `ClipOval` as seen in the code below:

```dart
ClipOval(
  child: CameraPreview(controller)
)
```